# app.use ("*") seems to be calling function multiple times

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, mongoose, ejs

`app.use("*", topUsers)` is called multiple times..

`topUsers` is being called multiple times

```
function topUsers(req, res, next){
    console.log("req.url", req.url)
    findMostUsefullReviewsAggregate(6)
    .then(function(aggregationResult){
        // console.log("aggregationResult", aggregationResult)
        // console.log("***aggregationResult::",  aggregationResult)
        return populateMostUseful(aggregationResult)
    })
    .then(function(populated){
        console.log("<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<TOPUSER CALLED >>>>>>>>>>>>")

        // console.log("POPULATED: ", populated);
        console.log(">>>populateMostUseful.length");

            populated = populated.map(function(e){
                e.momented = moment(e.createdAt.getTime()).fromNow();
                return e;
            })

            req.session.mostUsefulReviews = populated;

        // res.end()
    })
    .catch(function(err){
        console.log("HEADERERR", err);
    });

    next();
}
```

( some info for later: main.ejs is for `("/")`)

when I change it to `app.get("/", topUsers)` and go to `"/"`it is only called once (which is what I want).

the console.log for req.url shows "/" for all 3

In my `main.ejs` I include a `header.ejs`. I thought that might be a problem. Maybe the request to the header for the include was a problem but I don't think so.

Quick question : If I do app.get("/") would that work on all subroutes  like `/users/idofuser`? I think If I do that the function doesn't get called.

I think `app.get("*")` also gives me the same problem with the multiple calls.

Edit: when I put `next` in the `.then()` it still gets called multiple times.

my real goal it to have something happen on all routes. I already have routes set up. I don't want to go to each route and do something like app.get("/", onemiddleware, topUsers, ). I don't want to put topUSers on each one physically. Do I have to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are doing this from a browser loading a web page, the browser is probably requesting multiple resources from the website.

For starters, it often requests the favicon and if there are any other resources in the web page (other scripts, stylesheets, images, etc...) each of those will be a separate request to your web page.  You can see exactly what URL is being requested by logging `req.url` for each request.  From a single page load, there should be no reason you would get three requests for `/`, but you very well could get a request for `/` follow by other requests for some other resource (and consequently some other URL) from the same server.

Show us the web page you are loading and we can better point out what's going on.

---

If what you're really trying to do is to share a middleware on a set of routes, then you can create a router, put the middleware on the router with `router.use()`, define all the routes that you want to have that middleware on that specific router and then hook the router into your app.  This will execute the middleware only for routes that match that router and you only have to specify the middleware once for the router and all routes defined on that router will use that middleware.  Other routes defined directly on the `app` object or on other routers will not use the middleware.  You will have to define the router as some unique path root or wildcard that helps express know which routes should be passed into your router.  We'd have to see the whole universe of paths you plan to use that both do and don't use that middleware for us to know more specifically what to suggest.

Comment: Is the way I use `app.use()` an ok way to add  middleware on all routes with out going to each route and adding in the middleware. I want all routes not some. I cant show the actual web page. Thanks for your help

Comment: `app.use(topUsers)` is the way to insert middleware for all routes and this has to be defined before any of the routes.  But, this has nothing to do with why it's getting called multiple times.

Comment: and the req.url showed 3 times the "/". I thought it would show other stuff.

Comment: Well, you are showing us NOTHING from what is calling your server so all we could do it make wild guesses.  If this is a browser, then look at the network tab in the debugger to see what it is doing and perhaps why.  We can't really help if you don't explain and show us how and why your server gets called.  Your express app does not call itself so how many times it gets called has nothing to do with the express code itself (unless you're repeating the same route definition multiple times).

Comment: I put the app.use at the top and now i see the url is `req.url /api/comps` and I do have `app.get("/api/comps"` in my code . so I don't want the middle-ware to be applied to that. **Now I see the req.urls are different**

Comment: I'd suggest putting each set of routes in a router and put the `/api/comps` into an `/api` router that does not have the middleware and the other routes into a router that does have the middleware.  This question feels a bit like an onion where you reveal more and more parts of the problem and observations about what is going on as we converse rather than just describing the whole problem once in your question.  That makes it pretty hard to get a clear answer quickly and makes it hard for anyone else to follow the whole context of the question.

Comment: Is it possible for you to delete this answer and I will delete this question. I know SO has a warning about deleting answered questions. Sorry it's like an onion.

Comment: @jackblank - I don't need you to delete the question.  If you edit the question to make it clear so it includes all requirements and all correct observations and then I can make sure I've answered it, you can accept an answer and that's how its all supposed to work.

Comment: Thanks for your help jfriend00 I appreciate your work. I showed my relevant code but it was hard to pinpoint why it was being called 3 times so I only included the function that was being called 3 times. because of you I put the `app.use()` to the top and I was able to see the other routes that were being called and added return next for those routes in the middle-ware. Thanks for your contribution. You're such an inspiration.